Python - Reddit (Clickable Button)
I want to make in selenium python script to click Upvote under a post.
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="t3_1crzl6x"]//div[2]/span/span/button[1]').click()

But so far what I understand whenever you move cursor on this upvote it changing also they blocking somehow xpath is there any other way to make it?
Thanks for anyone who trying to help me with it.
I would like to make it work and understand how it works

After you import selenium from webdriver                                        try :
upvote_button = webDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_bt_clickable((by.CSS_SELECTOR,'.arrow.up)))
upvote_button.click()


Didn't work for me that's what i did :
driver.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/Polska/comments/1cs16wo/bezdomny_zadomowi%C5%82_si%C4%99_u_mojej_babci/')
time.sleep(random_sleep(2, 4))
upvote_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.arrow.up')))
upvote_button.click()

And i'm getting arrow what i read is about shadow root but idk how to make it

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
